# Using MediaTracker to cache images in Swing Application

Tags: java, swing, image, caching

I have a Swing based financial ticker, that will display a financial symbol the price movement and an arrow for either up or down for each counter / company.

This ticker can have a lot on counters (up to 100), and see the need to cache the images symbols to boost performance.

I have tried following this [article](http://www.javacoffeebreak.com/articles/mediatracker/index.html) but fail to understand it, especially how  the MediaTracker class is going to cache the images. From what i can see, i place the images  in an array and still retrieve from the array.

Does anyone know how it works and is supposed to be used?

Comment: where do you load the image(s) from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A MediaTracker will help you keep a track on loading lots of images, but that's about it. Once all is loaded you'll be need something like a good old Map with the images hashed against either the filename or the company name or ID.

```
private Map<String,Image> imageCache = new HashMap<String,Image>();
```

There's a reasonable example of using a MediaTracker to load images on the 1.4 JavaDocs: http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/MediaTracker.html. Note that there's no getImage() method, and you need an int id in order to track them. You have to maintain the BufferedImage references yourself, hence the HashMap<>.